# noUiSlider transparency

Tags: javascript, css, nouislider

I am using noUiSlider range slider. Here is jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/oun5p1xz/

```
behaviourSlider = document.getElementById('slider');

noUiSlider.create(behaviourSlider, {
    start: [ 30, 40 ],
    step: 10,
    behaviour: 'drag',
    connect: true,
    range: {
        'min':  20,
        'max':  80
    }
});
```

I want to make slider transparent, and only selected range should have color, but so far I achieve that because when I make right part transparent I see underlying range color:

https://jsfiddle.net/oun5p1xz/1/

Do you have any ideas?

UPDATED:

I want slider background to be an image:
[image]

Comment: I think this is not possible. See issue: https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/issues/363

Answer (score 0):

As far as my comment said it is not possible you can still tweak it. You have to make sure that the background of the slider is the same as, for example your `body` or `div` or any other DOM object their background, then you will get the desired result. This is the CSS I use:

```
body{
   background-color:#fff;
   margin:20px;
}
#slider {
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.noUi-target{
   border:0;
   box-shadow:none
}
#slider .noUi-background {
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

Live in action: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mntfe1xk/)

---

Based on your updated question I modified the CSS and now I use the following CSS:

```
body{   
   margin:20px;
}
#slider {
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0);
}
.noUi-connect{
   background: transparent;
   box-shadow:none;
}
.noUi-base{
   background-color: transparent;
   background-image:url(http://wallpapercave.com/wp/tmx6W6N.png);
}
#slider .noUi-background {
  background: transparent;
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

Live Demo [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mntfe1xk/1/)

Comment: But selected range color must differ from the rest.

Comment: @user2412672 that is not possible

Comment: @user2412672 , if you really want that I should recommend you use an other library. jQuery UI slider will do this easily see: https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/slider/range.html